# node not caught though path is given

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<case lang="en" type="Report" source="original">
    <case.head corrigendum="no">
        <party.line corrigendum="no" lang="en">
            <party role="Plaintiff">Da Costa</party>
            <party role="Defendant">Yih Lorenzo</party>
        </party.line>
        <citation.group>
            <primary.citation>[2014] 2 HKLRD 246</primary.citation>
            <parallel.citation type="Unreported">[2014] HKEC 356</parallel.citation>
            <parallel.citation type="West.serial">2032232950</parallel.citation>
            <parallel.citation type="WL.cite">2014 WL 6334</parallel.citation>
        </citation.group>
        <court.line>
            <court type="court">CA</court>
        </court.line>
        <case.ref.no.group>
            <case.ref.no>
                <prefix>HCMP</prefix>
                <number>2696</number>
                <year>2013</year>
            </case.ref.no>
        </case.ref.no.group>

        <judge.line lang="en" type="court">
            <judge>
                <name>Kwan</name>
                <job.title prefix="no">JA</job.title>
            </judge>
            <judge>
                <name>Macrae</name>
                <job.title prefix="no">JA</job.title>
            </judge>
        </judge.line>
        <publication_date yyyymmdd="20140304"/>
        <date.group lang="en">
            <date.line>Date of Decision on Costs: <date yyyymmdd="20140124" significance="judgment" type="Report">24 January 2014</date></date.line>
        </date.group>
        <counsel.group lang="en">
            <counsel.line>Written submissions by Ms Elizabeth Cheung, instructed by Reed Smith Richards Butler, for the 1st plaintiff / respondent (Mr Jose Miranda Da Costa Junior).</counsel.line>
            <counsel.line>Written submissions by Mr Norman Nip, instructed by Laracy &amp; Co, for the 1st defendant / applicant (Mr Lorenzo Yih).</counsel.line>
        </counsel.group>
    </case.head>
    <catchwords.group>
        <catchwords type="Report" lang="en">
            <catchword level="1" index="yes" italic="no">Civil procedure</catchword>
            <catchword level="2" index="yes" italic="no">costs</catchword>
            <catchword level="3" index="yes" italic="no">indemnity costs</catchword>
            <catchword index="yes" italic="no">discretion to award indemnity costs not fettered or circumscribed beyond requirement that taxation on indemnity basis must be appropriate</catchword>
        </catchwords>
        <catchwords type="Report" lang="zh">
            <catchword level="1" index="yes" italic="no">民事訴訟程序</catchword>
            <catchword level="2" index="yes" italic="no">訟費</catchword>
            <catchword level="3" index="yes" italic="no">按彌償基準的訟費</catchword>
            <catchword index="yes" italic="no">判給彌償訟費的酌情決定權不受束縛或規限以免偏離按彌償基準評定必須適當的規定</catchword>
        </catchwords>
    </catchwords.group>
    <headnotes lang="en">
        <para>D1’s application for leave </para>
        <para>7 HKCFAR 114 applied). (See paras.2–4.)</para>
        <para.group>
            <heading>Application</heading>
            <para>This was an applic</para>
        </para.group>
    </headnotes>
    <ref.group>
        <other.mentioned> 
            <other.ref type="Miscellaneous"><author>Practice Direction 14.3 (Costs)</author><book.title></book.title><ed_vol>para.13</ed_vol></other.ref>
        </other.mentioned>
    </ref.group>
    <judgment lang="en">
        <judge.block>
            <heading align="left"><judgename>Kwan JA</judgename> (giving the decision of the Court)</heading>
            <para><label>1.</label> In our decision
            <para><label>3.</label> We do not agree that the court’s discretion to order indemnity costs should be fettered in the manner as contended. This discretion is not to be fettered or circumscribed beyond the requirement that taxation on an indemnity basis must be appropriate (
            <case.considered>
                    <case.ref BVtable="yes" annotation="applied">
                        <citetitle type="case" full="Town Planning Board v Society for Protection of the Harbour Ltd (No 2)" legtype="ord">Town Planning Board v Society for Protection of the Harbour Ltd (No 2)</citetitle>
                        <citecitation full="(2004) 7 HKCFAR 114, [2004] 2 HKLRD 95">(2004) 7 HKCFAR 114</citecitation>
                    </case.ref>
                </case.considered>, 124 [17]).</para>

            <para><label>6.</label> On the b</para>
            <para.group>
                <heading align="right">Reported by Shin Su Wen</heading>
            </para.group>
        </judge.block>
    </judgment>
</case>
```

and below XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</meta>]]></xsl:text>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\Periodicals\XSLTS\NEW_289.css" type="text/css"></link>
            </head>
            <body>
                <section class="tr_chapter">
                    <div class="chapter">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="case">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="case.head"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="case.head">
        <div class="section-sect0">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:value-of select="./party.line/party[@role='Plaintiff']"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-sect0">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">and</xsl:text>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-sect0">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:value-of select="./party.line/party[@role='Defendant']"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="court.line|case.ref.no.group |judge.line|../judgement"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <div class="para">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="court.line">
        <hr></hr>
        <br />
        <div class="align-center">
            <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(./court/text(),'CFI')">
                    <xsl:text>Court of First Instance</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(./court/text(),'CA')">
                    <xsl:text>Court of Appeal</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="case.ref.no.group" name="new">
        <xsl:for-each select="case.ref.no">
            <div class="align-center">
                <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./prefix,'HCAJ')">
                        <xsl:text>Admiralty Action No </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./prefix,'HCAL')">
                        <xsl:text>Constitutional and Administrative Law List No </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./prefix,'CAAR')">
                        <xsl:text>Application for Review No </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./prefix,'CACV')">
                        <xsl:text>Civil Appeal No </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./prefix,'HCMP')">
                        <xsl:text>Miscellaneous Proceedings No </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./prefix,'HCMA')">
                        <xsl:text>Magistracy Appeal No </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:value-of select="./number"/>
                <xsl:text> of </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./year"/>
                <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <br />
        <hr></hr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="judge.line">
        <div class="section-sect3">
            <xsl:for-each select="judge">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="job.title"/>
                <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text> in </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(./@type,1,1)),substring(./@type,2))"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::date.group"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="date.group">
        <div class="section-sect4">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:value-of select="./date.line/date"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//catchwords.group/catchwords[@lang='en']"/>
        <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="//ref.group/leg.mentioned">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ref.group" mode="x"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//catchwords.group/catchwords[@lang='zh']"/>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catchwords.group/catchwords[@lang='en']">
        <div class="y">
            <xsl:for-each select="catchword">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@level=1">
                        <br/>
                        <span class="font-style-bolditalic">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </span>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">-</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:for-each select=".">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last()-1)">
                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> – </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref.group/leg.mentioned" mode="x">

    <div class="para"><xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="./leg.ref">
            <xsl:if test="./@considered='yes'">

                    <xsl:value-of select="citetitle"/>
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./leg.ptr.group/leg.ptr">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">, </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text></div>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="//catchwords.group/catchwords[@lang='zh']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catchwords.group/catchwords[@lang='zh']">

        <div class="y">
            <xsl:for-each select="catchword">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@level=1">
                        <br/>
                        <span class="font-style-bolditalic">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </span>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">-</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:for-each select=".">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last()-1)">
                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> – </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::headnotes"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="headnotes/para">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                <div class="x">
                    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
                </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <div class="m">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </div>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="para.group"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para.group">
        <div class="section-sect1">
            <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:for-each select="./para">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::label)]"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//counsel.group"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="list">
        <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="list.item/label"/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="orderitempara" match="list.item/label">
        <li class="item">
            <div class="para">
                <span class="item-num">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="./case.considered">
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </span>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::list.item"/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list.item">
        <xsl:variable name="a">
            <xsl:value-of select="./label"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./label">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::label|case.ref)]"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="counsel.group" name="j">
        <xsl:for-each select="./counsel.line">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="../following-sibling::ref.group/leg.mentioned">
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::ref.group/leg.mentioned" mode="y"/>
                                </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref.group/leg.mentioned" mode="y">
        <xsl:for-each select="./leg.ref">
            <xsl:if test="./@considered='no'">
                <div class="section-sect1">
                    <xsl:text>Legislation mentioned in the judgment</xsl:text>
                </div>
                <div class="para">
                    <xsl:value-of select="citetitle"/>
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./leg.ptr.group/leg.ptr">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">, </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::other.mentioned">
                <div class="section-sect1">
                    <xsl:text>Other materials mentioned in the judgment</xsl:text>
                </div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::other.mentioned"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <div class="section-sect1">
                    <xsl:text>Case cited in the judgment</xsl:text>
                </div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="case.considered"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
       <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::judgment"/>-->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="other.mentioned">
        <xsl:for-each select="other.ref">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:if test="./author/text()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./author"/>
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <span class="font-style-italic">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./book.title"/>
                </span>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./ed_vol"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="case.considered">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:if test="./case.ref">
                    <span class="font-style-italic">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./case.ref/citetitle[@full]"/>
                    </span>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./case.ref/citecitation/@full"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="judgment">
        <div class="section-sect1">
            <xsl:value-of select="./judge.block/heading"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:for-each select="./judge.block/para">
            <div class="parax">
                <span class="new">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./label"></xsl:value-of>
                </span>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::label)]"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="./judge.block/para.group">
            <xsl:if test="./heading">
            <xsl:choose>
                                                    <xsl:when test="./heading/@align">
                                                         <div class="{concat('para align-',./heading/@align)}">
                <span class="font-style-bold">
                         <xsl:value-of select="./heading/text()"/>      
                                                    </span>

                </div>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                          <div class="para">
                <span class="font-style-bold">
                         <xsl:value-of select="./heading/text()"/>      
                                                    </span>

                </div>                              
                                                                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:for-each select="para">
                <div class="parax">
                    <span class="new">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./label"></xsl:value-of>
                    </span>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>-->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::label)]"/>
                </div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./list"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="block.quote">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./list">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="list"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./para">
                <xsl:for-each select="./para">
                    <div class="extract">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./para.group">
                <xsl:for-each select="./para.group">
                    <div class="ali-itl">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
                    </div>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="./para.group">
                            <xsl:for-each select="./para.group">
                                <xsl:if test="./para">
                                    <div class="ali-itl">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="extract">
                                        <div class="para">
                                            <xsl:if test="./para/label">
                                                <div class="new">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="./para.group/para/label"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="./para/text()"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <div class="extract">
                                <div class="para">
                                    <xsl:if test="./para/label">
                                        <div class="new">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="./para.group/para/label"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="./para/text()"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="emphasis">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="citetitle">
                <span class="font-style-italic">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="./list.item"/>
                </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@type">
                <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@type)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <span class="{$fontStyle}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here i took `<xsl:apply-templates select="//case.considered"/>` and also there is a template for this, but the template is not being called, please let me know where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to boil down the XML and XSLT to the very essential? This us a lot to read! By the way: it would also be good to remove names and amounts from this apparently real life sample before uploading it!

Comment: Hi @MarcusRickert, thanks for responding, i've removed all the data that is not needed but with the tags in my XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are under the node `ref.group/leg.mentioned`. You can use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../../judgment//case.considered"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`case.considered` only occurs once in your XML source in the context of:

```
 /case[1]/judgment[1]/judge.block[1]/para[3]
```

That means that you can select it if you use any of these expressions:

- `//case.considered` from anywhere
- `case.considered` or `./case.considered` if you are in the context of `para`.

In your code you only use the latter. You mention using `//case.considered` in your question. If you do that it will work. If you replace `case.considered` for `//case.considered` in this block:

```
<xsl:otherwise>
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <xsl:text>Case cited in the judgment</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//case.considered"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

it *will* find and insert the text you are expecting.

Comment: i'm using `<xsl:apply-templates select="//case.considered"/>` but it is not getting called.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem. Perhaps you should review your question and try to adapt it to focus on the specific problem you are trying to solve - reducing the amount of code you included - and include the **actual** code you are having problems with (there is no `//case.considered` in your code).